# selinux folder in root directory (/)

Tags: xubuntu, selinux

While navigating through my files, I noticed a "selinux" folder in root (`/`); it doesn't have any files in it, has completely root(root) permissions, and when I [looked up about it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux), it seems to be some sort of server administration program or something.

It also appears to have become unattended since Karmic, and is apparently completely broken in Precise.  Just to make sure, I ran `sudo apt-get remove selinux` in the terminal, and sure enough, it said I had no such program installed.

Can I delete this folder? Is there anything else I should remove/purge?

Lastly, any ideas as to how this folder might have got here? I never installed selinux on my computer, as far as I can remember...

**Edit:** I also just noticed another folder called "srv".  It, as well, has no files in it and is owned by root. Is this folder related to the "selinux" folder, and can I delete it as well?

- Running Xubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the `/srv` folder, it is listed in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) as a data folder for system services.

There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libselinux/+bug/352193) from `libselinux` on Kubuntu a few years ago outlining the same basic question. It appears that the `2.0.65-5build1` version of `libselinux1` was (incorrectly) creating `/selinux` - maybe you have this build, or a similar unpatched one, installed?

Comment: Synaptic says I have v2.1.9-5ubuntu1 installed, which it also says is the latest.